# SSRS 2016 Scale-Out on Azure VMs not working

Tags: reporting-services, azure-virtual-machine, sql-server-2016, alwayson

**Setup**

I'm running an AlwaysOn SQL Server Availability Set (from the [Azure Always On SQL Server Availability Set Template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/sql-server-alwayson-cluster-template-updated-with-internal-listeners-and-optimized-performance/)), and trying to utilize the two SQL Servers in a scale-out NLB setup (I haven't figured out exactly what virtual appliance to use yet) for SSRS. I've never actually utilized a scale-out set-up for SSRS but it seems relatively straight-forward:

```
1. Set up one instance of SSRS
2. Create reportserver db
3. Connect to same report server db from a second SSRS instance
4. Accept the join request from SSRS Configuration tool of the first instance
```

Everything* seems to work fine up until step 4 when the join request doesn't appear [(see the screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRY5S.png).  The part of this that I imagine might be causing some issues is that due to the AlwaysOn Setup I am using an internal load balancer with sql listener for my SSRS connection string, and this can be pointed to either SQL Server instance at any given time based on failover, but I'm not sure how this could be troublesome.

**Things I've Tried**

*The below resulted in: 2nd instance not available to join, despite successful connection to database.*

- Scaling Out before adding Report Server to AlwaysOn
- Scaling Out after adding Report Server to AlwaysOn
- Using rskeymgmt Utility from the 1st instance (indicates success but no change on restarting SSRS service)

*The below resulted in: Primary scale-out instance changed from one instance to the other.*

- Restore encryption key from 1st instance to the 2nd instance after connecting to RS database.

None of this seems to work and I'm not sure if this is a bug in SQL Server 2016 or something wrong with my methodology.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

***Note**: I ran into some initial problems with loopbacks, but disabled strictnamechecking and allowed the specific dns names through the check (the host name for the load balancer (base and FQDN) and that of the server itself (base and FQDN).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Azure SQL Server Templates ship with identical InstallationID's in the report server config file.  Altering the GUID in the file resolves the issue.